# Implementar teclas arriba y abajo en autocompletar con php mysql javascripy jquery

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

tengo un código que lo que hace es traer una lista de filiales de la base y cuando la persona empieza a escribir un nombre aparece abajo la filial y para seleccionar se necesita usar el mouse, me gustaría implementar las teclas arriba y abajo del teclado para poder seleccionar la filial sin necesidad de usar solo el mouse.

Ese es mi código:

```
function autocompletar() {
var minimo_letras = 0;
var palabra = $('#filial_id').val();
if (palabra.length >= minimo_letras) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'mostrar.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {palabra:palabra},
        success:function(data){
            $('#lista_id').show();
            $('#lista_id').html(data);
        }
    });
} else {
    $('#lista_id').hide();
}
```

}

```
function set_item(opciones) {
$('#filial_id').val(opciones);
$('#lista_id').hide();
```

}

Gracias

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Gracias, pude resolver asi, solo son javascript